# Default sorting in Angular Material - Sort header

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I change Angular Material code below, so that data-table is sorted by 'name' column, ascending order by default. Arrow (indicating current sort direction) must be displayed.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Original code:

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
  <tr>
    <th mat-sort-header="name">Dessert (100g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="calories">Calories</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="fat">Fat (g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="carbs">Carbs (g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="protein">Protein (g)</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let dessert of sortedData">
    <td>{{dessert.name}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.calories}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.fat}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.carbs}}</td>
    <td>{{dessert.protein}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was trying something like this, but it doesn't work (no arrow displayed, not sorted)

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" matSortActive="name" matSortStart="asc" matSortDisableClear>
```

Here's link to [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iYVEwPwzLZkXjfk83Om8?p=preview)

Comment: Could call `this.sortData({active: "name", direction: "asc"})` on `ngOnInit` check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hsIXe6eKUX5RmkyVdrdw?p=preview)

Comment: @PankajParkar It's not correct solution. Table is sorted, but Sort header doesn't know about it and arrow (indicating current sort direction) is not displayed.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You're mistaking `matSortStart` for `matSortDirection`.

Try this:

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-defaultsort?file=src/app/sort-overview-example.html

`matSortStart` can be used to reverse the cycle used when sort (e.g. when the user clicks to sort, it starts at desc instead of asc).

Edit: Thanks Ben for providing an updated example

Comment: This method working only for the first time. After the table's dataSource was changed, I try to re-set the `matSortActive` and `matSortDirection` but the small arrow isn't displayed

Comment: The sample seems not working anymore, I made a new one:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-defaultsort?file=src/app/sort-overview-example.html

Comment: You can trigger sorting and fix the hidden arrow bug with [this solution](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10242#issuecomment-470726829). I'm using mat-sort-header without a data source, and this was the only fix that worked.

Comment: @GilEpshtain to fix this, use @Aman Madiiarbekov`s answer below.

Comment: Hello, if my table implements pagination, how can I ensure that the ``active`` and ``direction`` parameters are carried over to the next page?

Comment: Not working in your provided stackblitz also

Answer (score 69):

You can programmatically sort the table by invoking the `sort(Sortable)` method of the data source. Assuming you've got a `dataSource` component property for the data source:

```js
// to put next to the class fields of the component
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort
    
// to put where you want the sort to be programmatically triggered, for example inside ngOnInit
this.sort.sort(({ id: 'name', start: 'asc'}) as MatSortable);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

Comment: This is kind of what I'm looking for but the only issue is it triggers the `matSortChange` event. Is there a way to set sort without triggering the event?

Comment: No. That is how the sort gets called. Why don't you want the matSortChange event to be triggered?

Comment: because I have it set to update a cookie with `asc`/`desc` of a column and if it is called each time page is loaded then every time it will be different

Comment: If you're using mat-sort-header *without* a data source, you can trigger sorting programmatically with this solution: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10242#issuecomment-470726829

Comment: This only worked the first time for me, after initializing the table another time the order was wrong. The answer below from @Aman Madiiarbekov did the job for me.

Comment: @TobiasKaufmann - For me, I am not having that issue. Whether I reload the page with a browser refresh or a route change, the column sorting always happens as specified

Comment: I needed to drop this in AfterViewInit instead of OnInit, or order for the ViewChild to be populated.

Answer (score 29):

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

const sortState: Sort = {active: 'name', direction: 'desc'};
this.sort.active = sortState.active;
this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);
```

should work. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-sort-default?file=app/table-sorting-example.ts)

And to show sorting direction arrow, add next css (workaround)

```
th.mat-header-cell .mat-sort-header-container.mat-sort-header-sorted .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transform: translateY(0) !important;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations along with your code, so that later user can follow your ideas/code more easily.

Comment: I used the sort from [Nino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51787040/715342) and the CSS workaround here to get my programmatically-set sort to show the arrow.

Comment: In angular 7 I just set the this.sort = { active: 'name', direction: 'desc' }; and I did not have to add any CSS changes for the arrow to be active.

Comment: Nick Gallimore maybe you are adding your css not in correct place?
try to add it in a main global css file (it can be in the assets/css/...css)

Comment: If you don't want to use !important, you can also fix the hidden arrow with JS: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10242#issuecomment-470726829

Comment: I am just wondering how did use `sort` var of `ViewChild` in `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 11):

**Update for Material** (tested with v7.3):

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) matSort: MatSort;

private someMethod(): void {
  this.matSort.sort({ id: 'columnName', start: 'asc', disableClear: false });
}
```

This will also update the `mat-sort-header`'s arrow without any workaround

Answer (score 10):

You can bind mat-table sort properties to your component variable also.

As @Andrew Seguin says:

```
<table matSort matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="asc">
```

This is proper way to set default sorting if you know which one is that.

In case that you get sorting from somewhere else (in my case from query string params), you can also do it like this (sorting arrows works perfectly here):

```
sortProperty: 'name',  // this can be changed or filled in any time
sortDirection: 'asc',


<mat-table matSort [matSortActive]="sortProperty" [matSortDirection]="sortDirection">
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several contributing factors that affect the behaviour. Mostly it's use of [MatTableDataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) vs a hand-crafted derivative of [DataSource](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/71b7b15958ee732fbe1398d68705143eb0e820e3/tools/public_api_guard/cdk/collections.d.ts#L58). So different solutions may work in some cases and don't in others.

Anyway, it's an old [bug that's been well covered on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10242). Please upvote that GitHub issue to attract attention of the Angular team.

The most durable solution published on that GitHub thread ([link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10242#issuecomment-470726829)) is to call the following method on applying a sorting order:

```
public setSort(id: string, start?: 'asc' | 'desc') {
    start = start || 'asc';
    const matSort = this.dataSource.sort;
    const toState = 'active';
    const disableClear = false;

    //reset state so that start is the first sort direction that you will see
    matSort.sort({ id: null, start, disableClear });
    matSort.sort({ id, start, disableClear });

    //ugly hack
    (matSort.sortables.get(id) as MatSortHeader)._setAnimationTransitionState({ toState });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case sorting was not working because **matColumDef** id and mat-cell var is different

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="mat-table-header">First Name</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{ item.name}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

after making changes matColumnDef="firstName" to matColumnDef="**name**" which is same as item.**name**

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="mat-table-header">First Name</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{ item.name}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

it works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Andrew Seguin (first and accepted answer) did the visual trick for me, but it **didn't** **sort** the table.

My solution is to use the html code provided by @Andrew Seguin and call the *sortData(sort: Sort)* method myself, but how to do that?
As specified in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api), the ,,Sort'' is an interface which hast two properties, active and direction and the interface must look something like that:

```
export interface Sort {
   active:string //The id/name of the column being sorted
   direction:string //asc or dsc depending on the use case (The sort direction)
}
```

So the trick is to call the sortData(sort: Sort) method in ngOnInit as follows:

```
ngOnInit(){
    //Do some nitialization
    this.sortData({active:'name', direction:'asc'});
}

sortData(sort: Sort) {
    //Your sorting algorithm (see examples in documentation, link above and at the bottom)
}
```

The HTML code is as in the accepted answer ;-)
Hope this helps anyone,
Alex

[Documentation examples](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have you tried to call on the init of the page the sort function forced on name and direction?

```
     ngOnInit() {
    let defSort: Sort = {};
    defSort.direction = 'asc';
    defSort.active = 'name';
    this.sortData(defSort);
  }
```

Comment: It's not correct solution. Table is sorted, but Sort header doesn't know about it and arrow (indicating current sort direction) is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

I had to make default sort on load

```
const matSort = { id: defaultSort.name } as MatSortable;
this.sort.direction = defaultSort.sort === 'asc' ? '' : defaultSort.sort === 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc' as SortDirection;
this.sort.sort(matSort);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add sort programmatically add this on your css.

`::ng-deep.mat-header-cell .mat-sort-header-container.mat-sort-header-sorted .mat-sort-header-arrow   { opacity: 1 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code

```
   ngAfterViewInit{
          this.sort.disableClear = true;
          this.sort.sort({disableClear: true, id:sortEnabledColumns.id,start:'asc'})
   }
```

Without the first line it will go to default hide status when you click third time

Answer (score 0):

```
I found this in Github, works fine for me
      
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
     //reset state so that start is the first sort direction that you will see
    this.sort.sort({ id: null, start: 'desc', disableClear: true });
    this.sort.sort({ id: 'FieldNameToSort', start: 'asc', disableClear: true });
    this.sort.sortChange.emit(this.sort);
    (this.sort.sortables.get('FieldNameToSort') as MatSortHeader)._setAnimationTransitionState({ toState: 'active' });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.