# How to sort MatTableDataSource programmatically?

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, mat-table

I'm trying to sort the MatTableDataSource programmatically so that I can sort the data via the use of a button rather than by the table column header when viewing the data in a specific mobile layout. However, I'm having trouble doing so.

I've followed [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51787040/8216367) advice on how to do it but the data sort is not being reflected. The mobile layout design for using the same data as the table:

```
<mat-card matSort *ngFor="let item of dataSource.filteredData">
```

The function I'm using to try and sort the data is:

```
sortDataSource(id: string, start: string){
  this.dataSource.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({id: id, start: start}));
}
```

which is called from tapping onto a button within a mat-menu e.g.

```
<mat-menu #sortMenu="matMenu" yPosition="below" [overlapTrigger]="false">
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="sortDataSource('createdDate', 'asc')"><span>Creation Date</span><mat-icon>arrow_upward</mat-icon></button>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

[Link to StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrkpa8)

Edit: Adding where I'm assigning the data to the table's dataSource which comes from an Observable array:

```
this.data$.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Edit 2: Removed error image as fixed by add "matSort" to the the `mat-card` using `*ngFor` for creating the mobile layout version of the `mat-table`.

Comment: Where do you define `this.dataSource`? You are not actually sorting anything but rather setting a sorting id and direction.

Comment: Within the ngOnInit. I'm able to sort the data fine when using the mat-table's column headers but I'm trying to sort it with the use of a button instead by using the MatTableDataSource's methods but I can't find much documentation on it.

Comment: The mat-sort directive is connected to the table and therefore sorts the data, but manually doing it is different. Please post your dataSource code

Comment: Added in edit as requested.

Comment: Managed to fix the error message as said by the edit but the sort is still not being reflected by the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

A bug was already reported to the Material team over at [Github.com](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10242). It seems that this is currently not possible. Please use a manual approach or implement your own sorting header.

---

Try manually sorting the data of the datasource:

```
sortDataSource(id: string, start: string) {
    this.dataSource.sort.sort(<MatSortable>({ id: id, start: start }));
    this.dataSource.data.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.createdDate < b.createdDate) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.createdDate > b.createdDate) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

You can easily make this more generic using the id and start parameters of your function.

Comment: I don't really want to be manually sorting the data though. I want a way of accessing the MatTableDataSource's inbuilt method of sorting since I'm already defining how to sort the data within the `this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor` method so that I can emulate the way of pressing onto a column header via the use of a button by passing the `id` and `start` props through. Maybe it's just not possible to do that?

Comment: Okay added one. The sort button above the table opens up a mat-menu which then uses the sort function when selecting an item.

Comment: Aaaa okay that explains it then! Yeah will just have to do it manually at the moment then. Thanks!

Comment: A shorter way would be 
this.dataSource.data.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
  return a.createdDate - b.createdDate ;
}

-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Or even shorter with asc or desc:  
this.dataSource.data.sort(
      (a, b) => {
        return start === 'asc' ? a[id] - b[id] : (start === 'desc' ? b[id] - a[id] : a[id] - b[id]); // Last is default
      }
    );

Answer (score 4):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-sort-default-ytu6ch

check this out!

instead of manually sorting with the array.sort
we can make use of the
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
and
import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';

to sort based on condition.

Answer (score 1):

When you reassign `dataSource.sort` with `matSort`, the template gets notified on the change and represent the changes.

`component.ts`

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) matSort: MatSort;

  orderData(id: string, start?: 'asc' | 'desc') {
    const matSort = this.dataSource.sort;
    const toState = 'active';
    const disableClear = false;

    matSort.sort({ id: null, start, disableClear });
    matSort.sort({ id, start, disableClear });

    this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort;
  }
```

`component.html`

```
<button mat-raised-button
   (click)="orderData('nameOfColumn', 'asc')">ASC</button>
<button mat-raised-button
   (click)="orderData('nameOfColumn', 'desc')">DESC</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Might be the shortest sort manually function for Material Table**

Here is my short solution combined with JavaScript:

```
sortDataSource(idVal: string, startVal?: string): void {
    this.dataSource.data.sort(
        (a, b) => {
            return startVal === 'asc' ? a[idVal] - b[idVal] : (startVal === 'desc' ? b[idVal] - a[idVal] : a[idVal] - b[idVal]);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work with nested objects inside your datasource just place following in your datasource initialization routine:

```
...

this.dataSource.sort = new MatSort()

this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = _.get
```

Where  _.get is a lodash function (https://docs-lodash.com/v4/get/)

My sorting function that is called whenever my sorting select control changes is as follows:

```
private sortDataSource(sortItem: SortItem) {
        console.log('Sort:: ', sortItem)

        this.dataSource.sort.sort(<MatSortable>{
            id: 'ad.createdAt',
            start:
                sortItem.sortOrder === SortOrder.ASCENDING ? 'asc' : 'desc',
            disableClear: true,
        })
        this.dataSource.data.sort(
            (a: any, b: any) => {
                
                if (
                    a['ad']['createdAt'] <
                    b['ad']['createdAt']
                ) {
                    if (sortItem.sortOrder === -1) {
                        return -1
                    } else {
                        return 1
                    }
                } else if (
                    a['ad']['createdAt'] >
                    b['ad']['createdAt']
                ) {
                    if (sortItem.sortOrder === -1) {
                        return 1
                    } else {
                        return -1
                    }
                } else {
                    return 0
                }
            }
        )

    }
```

For the sake of completeness here is my SortItem interface thats used to specify sort items:

```
export interface SortItem {
    title: string
    adProperty: string
    sortOrder: SortOrder
}

export enum SortOrder {
    DESCENDING = -1, // 'descending',
    ASCENDING = 1, // 'ascending'
}
```