# Default sort angular mat table arrow not being set

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to get my Material table to first load with a column sorted and have the header arrow set to show that it is sorted. I added the following to my table to sort the table by default when loaded:

```
<table matSort matSortActive="name" matSortStart="asc" matSortDisableClear>
```

This seems to work and the data is sorted but the header arrow does no reflect the sort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define the default sort before you set the sorter of your datasource.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.sort.sort(({ id: 'name', start: 'asc'}) as MatSortable);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

[Working Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjhmmp)

Comment: It worked for me. The arrow being set took a litle bit of time to me because in my case i was putting this code on the ngAfterViewInit(). For some reason it does not work. Moving it to the ngInit() start to work immediately. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with mat sort arrow not being displayed.
One issue, while not exactly the same as yours, provides a working, programmatic solution: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10242
It was the only workaround that worked for me.
For specific code see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65501143/407758