# How can I sort the mat table data in descending order by default on date?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table like this,

```
<table mat-table [data]="tableData" matSort matSortDirection="desc" (sortChange)="sortTable($event)" multiTemplateDataRows>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</td>
    <tr mat-cell *matCellDef="let tdata">{{tdata.name}}</tr>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date</td>
    <tr mat-cell *matCellDef="let tdata">{{tdata.date}}</tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Default sorting order seems to be ascending when the table first loads. I want to change it to descending order by date. How can I achieve that? I tried adding `matSortDirection` but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default sorting in Angular Material - Sort header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46743115/default-sorting-in-angular-material-sort-header)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [matSortActive] and matSortDirection directives on the mat-table. Also I have changed the matColumnDef on your second ng-container to date:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableData" matSort [matSortActive]="'date'" matSortDirection="desc" (matSortChange)="sortTable($event)" multiTemplateDataRows>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</td>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let tdata">{{tdata.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date</td>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let tdata">{{tdata.date}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableData" matSort matSortDirection="desc" (matSortChange)="sortTable($event)" multiTemplateDataRows>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</td>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let tdata">{{tdata.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
    <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header matSortDirection="desc">Date</td>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let tdata">{{tdata.date}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['name', 'date']"></tr>
</table>
```